# Can I mix packages from foxy and humble?

Tags: ros, ros2, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Community,

currently i using ROS2 Foxy and ROS1 Noetic on the same PC.
In the beginning I wanted to use Humble but it only supports Ubuntu 22.04.
In order to use ROS1 noetic and ROS2 distribution, i have to use foxy.
Now i have noticed that ros2 foxy only smac planner

My question:

I downloaded the ros2 nav2 stack in my underlay directory /opt/ros/foxy/. So i assume that it is not enough just to download the packages (Controller and planner), add them to the share folder and make changes to the package.xml and cmakelist right?
For instance, the folders are named different (Example: Humble -> nav2_smac_planner && Foxy ->smac_planner). Also i think i have to create a overlay workspace for the ros2 nav2.

-->In general, can i add the planners and controllers in my ros2 foxy system or are they only supported for humble?<--

Thank you very much !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414709/can-i-mix-packages-from-foxy-and-humble?/) by [Nartmangnourt](https://answers.ros.org/users/143866/nartmangnourt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-05-07**:
I edited your title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, the packages that rely on a later version of ROS are not downgradable to anything below it. You will need to change the source code to make it compile and work in the same way, which might be complex or even impossible.

---

Originally posted by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) with karma: 501 on 2023-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nartmangnourt](https://answers.ros.org/users/143866/nartmangnourt/) on 2023-04-24**:
Hey Per Edwardsson,

thanks a lot for your answer. I believe i will just use the planner and controller which are available for ros2 foxy.

I really appreciate your help ;)